# Does WordPress have a built-in function to duplicate posts?

Tags: wordpress

I want to duplicate some posts programmatically without comments.

Does WordPress have a built-in function to duplicate posts?

Comment: I dont think WP has such feature by default in core.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `wp_insert_post()` function to duplicate a post.

You just need to remove the post ID from the data you pass to it, and Wordpress will create a new post instead of updating an existing one. E.g.

```php
    $post_id = 1234;
    $post = (array) get_post( $post_id ); // Post to duplicate.
    unset($post['ID']); // Remove id, wp will create new post if not set.
    wp_insert_post($post);
```

Comments are stored in a different table. And are linked by the post ID. As the duplicate post will have a different ID the original comments will not be associated with it.

Comment: Thanks. But what happens to custom fields, custom taxonomy? Those also should duplicate

Comment: Meta & Terms would need to be copied separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only copy the post, you can use @ngearing's solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56437515/3480821

If you want to duplicate the post with its meta and terms as well, you can use the following function:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Duplicates a post & its meta and returns the new duplicated Post ID.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The Post ID you want to clone.
 * @return int The duplicated Post ID.
 */
function duplicate_post(int $post_id): int
{
    $old_post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$old_post) {
        // Invalid post ID, return early.
        return 0;
    }

    $title = $old_post->post_title;

    // Create new post array.
    $new_post = [
        'post_title'  => $title,
        'post_name'   => sanitize_title($title),
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_type'   => $old_post->post_type,
    ];

    // Insert new post.
    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    // Copy post meta.
    $post_meta = get_post_custom($post_id);
    foreach ($post_meta as $key => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            add_post_meta($new_post_id, $key, maybe_unserialize($value));
        }
    }

    // Copy post taxonomies.
    $taxonomies = get_post_taxonomies($post_id);
    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        $term_ids = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy, ['fields' => 'ids']);
        wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, $term_ids, $taxonomy);
    }

    // Return new post ID.
    return $new_post_id;
}
```

I have also made this function available in a [Github gist here](https://gist.github.com/eduwass/90c36565c41ac01cafe3).

Answer (score 0):

No, there does not exists such functionality like duplicate post in WordPress core.

To meet  your requirement you can use this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-duplicator/

This plugin duplicate the post but not comment. See there documentation